# Responsive header menu with background image

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, responsive-images

I'm trying to create a responsive header with a background image. When I add the off-canvass menu hamburger icon, I get a band of body background displayed at the top of the viewport.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
  html,
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    font: 16px/1.75 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
  }
  .toggle {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.15em;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white
  }
  .wrapper {
    max-width: 78.75em;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0)
  }
  .container {
    background: yellow;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
  }
  #header label {
    padding: 0 0.125em;
    font: 2.875em/1.4375em Arial
  }
  #header label:hover,
  #menu label:hover {
    color: grey
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- red -->
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
    </div>
    <!-- closing "#menu" -->
    <div class="container">
      <!-- yellow -->
      <div id="header">
        <img src="http://www.dragsdownunder.info/ralph/forums/greenbox.jpg" style="float:left; margin:0 0 0 0; max-width:100%; height:auto; border:0" alt="green box" title="green box">
        <label for="main-nav-check" class="toggle" onclick="" title="Menu">&#x2261;</label>
      </div>
      <!-- closing "#header" -->

      <h1>Test header 4</strong></h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no pro mundi graeco pertinacia, et lorem conceptam complectitur sea. Eam no persecuti scriptorem. Ius an sadipscing consectetuer. Purto nostrum mel in. Ne sea congue homero.</p>

    </div>
    <!-- closing ".container" -->
  </div>
  <!-- closing ".wrapper" -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you are talking about red bar above header? then add overflow:hidden in .container class.

Comment: Thank you Leo, that seems to be the answer.

Comment: m happy that i was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

> I think problem is solved, have a look

```css
html,
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    font: 16px/1.75 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
  }
  .toggle {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.15em;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white
  }
  .wrapper {
    max-width: 78.75em;
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0)
  }
  .container {
    background: yellow;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
  }
  #header label {
    padding: 0 0.125em;
    font: 2.875em/1.4375em Arial
  }
  #header label:hover,
  #menu label:hover {
    color: grey
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- red -->
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
    </div>
    <!-- closing "#menu" -->
    <div class="container">
      <!-- yellow -->
      <div id="header">
        <img src="http://www.dragsdownunder.info/ralph/forums/greenbox.jpg"  style="max-width:100%; height:auto; border:0" alt="green box" title="green box">
        <label for="main-nav-check" class="toggle" onclick="" title="Menu">&#x2261;</label>
      </div>
      <!-- closing "#header" -->

      <h1>Test header 4</strong></h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, no pro mundi graeco pertinacia, et lorem conceptam complectitur sea. Eam no persecuti scriptorem. Ius an sadipscing consectetuer. Purto nostrum mel in. Ne sea congue homero.</p>

    </div>
    <!-- closing ".container" -->
  </div>
  <!-- closing ".wrapper" -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: well please check back.menu icon is in next row while it should be in green row..